# regex in php to remove portion of strings

Tags: php, regex

in the code below:

```
<a href="http://example.com/yadayada" yada-yadayada="/yada/yadayada/yadayada.php?x=12345&amp;yadayadayasomehtmltagandgiberishtexthere
```

how do I write a regex in php that will remove everything before `x=` and everything after `&am` so I will only get the value `12345` which is just an example but in actual, it varies.

Comment: Have you looked at [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)?

Comment: Could you show a more concrete example of what you're matching against?

Comment: @Jack in the code `yadayada.php?x=12345&amp;yada` I want to match everything before and after `12345` so i can delete them all leaving only the `12345` which i am interested. note that the `12345` is just an example but it varies.

Comment: Last time I checked HTML doesn't have `yada-yadayada` attributes; that's what I mean by "more concrete".

Comment: @Jack those were just an example and its not important. whats important to me is everything after`x=` and before `&amp`. so i can delete both the `x=` and everything before it and also delete `&amp` and everything after it leaving only whats between `x=` and `&amp`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have extracted the whole URL using `DOMDocument`:

```
// $url = '/yadayada?x=12345&y=7890';
parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $arr);
echo $arr['x'];
```

See also: [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str)

Comment: This is far more robust than using regex as you can specify exactly the parameter you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use simple `\d` that matches numbers [0-9]:

```
$text = '<a href="http://example.com/yadayada" yada-yadayada="/yada/yadayada/yadayada.php?x=12345&amp;yadayadayasomehtmltagandgiberishtexthere';
preg_match_all("#x=(\d+)(&amp;|&)#", $text, $match);
print_r($match[1]);//12345
```

Update: pattern changed to `x=(\d+)(&amp;|&)`

Comment: those values after `x=` varies. so in the actual its not just 12345. If I can match the `x=` before 12345 and the `&amp`so I can remove them leaving just the dynamic number (which in my example is 12345) will solve my problem.

Comment: Simple. Use `x=(\d+)&amp`

Comment: @Herbert how do i use `x=(\d+)&amp`

Answer (score 0):

ok I solved it using @Akam and @Herberts help.

preg_match_all("#x=(\d+)&amp#", $url, $match);
print_r($match[1]);

thanks guys!

Comment: Glad you got it working, but I still think @Jack's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17892021/911182) is a better solution. Using regex for this type of problem is really just a hack.